# Azure Growing Sql Database

Tags: azure-sql-database

1.I am new in azure, I want to know can we have same replication mechanism provided by on premise sql on azure sql db?

2 .Issue we are facing is, few of the tables are growing fast, daily insert around 10k records, so we are planning to keep only few months say 6 data on main DB and copy all data to other DB using replication (not sure if feasible).
We need to read data from backup as well in application for some reports.

Please suggest on this if replication will work or any other solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Geo-replication uses a version of AlwaysOn with async replicas under the hood. It is very similar to a distributed Availability Group in SQL 2016, but you cannot control it, you can only turn it on or off.
2. Replication will work for that, but it would replicate all the data in the DB, not just the tables you want.

Link to Azure Documentation: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-geo-replication-overview/

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.
Few queries
1. As you said it will replicate all tables it will be fine but can we replicate limited data of particular period not instead of all data.
2. Can we schedule replication ?
If possible please share any document or link related to azure sql replication.

Comment: I've updated the answer with the link. 1. No you cannot choose what to replicate. The whole DB gets replicated. 2. No, it happens all the time using Async calls. (Yes, both standard and active geo-replication use asynchronous replication to ensure there is no impact on the primary database from the replication) https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-geo-replication-portal/

Comment: region redundant replica is by default. geo redundancy you have to specifically mark it. and it costs extra. as far as the increasing size , In Azure sql you can only scale up or down by changing the service tiers and performance levels.

Comment: replica costs nothing, you only pay for the second db instance

Comment: One more doubt, I also read somewhere about partitioning.
What will be better approach, replication or partitioning?

Comment: sorry, forgot to answer this one, well, to me those aren't similar, yes you could partition data to have some data in westeurope and some in asia, but that doesn't act like replication at all, thats separation.

Comment: Is there way of replication on same region, I dont want geo replication which will replicate on other location?

Comment: you get that for free, sql is automatically replicated in the region, so you don't lose data